# MATLAB: How can I cancel ("NaN" value) elements of a matrix based on another matrix's "NaN" values?

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan, relate

Let's suppose I have a matrix A=

```
 1     2     3;
 4     5     6;
 7     8     9
```

and a matrix B=

```
1      NaN    3; 
NaN    5      6;  
7      NaN    NaN
```

I want to cancel the same elements that are canceled in matrix B. It would be:

A2=

```
 1     NaN     3;
 NaN     5     6;
 7     NaN     NaN
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use logical indexing: `A2=A ; A2(isnan(B))=NaN ;`

Comment: @Hoki: Answers in the answers section please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create the new matrix A2 such that each element is `a2 = b - b + a`.

This relies on the fact that NaN propagates through the expression evaluation, and `b - b` is essentially a no-op in all other instances.

It is also guaranteed never to overflow your type.

Comment: _a no-op in all other instances_ except if `b = inf`